# Jupyter Notebook runs my code abnormally slowly

Tags: python, performance, jupyter-notebook, curve-fitting

**Edit**: this is my second ever post on this website. I'm trying my best to follow guidelines and etiquette, but I've done some mistakes. I've almost entirely re-written the original post, to make it clearer and easier to understand.

**Disclaimer**: I'm only familiar with Matlab as an amateur programmer and Physics student, so please be patient. I should be learning Python in a lab course I'm attending during these months, but due to apparent misunderstandings we have been told to learn Python basics on our own. Moreover, English is not my first language. Please, be patient, and thank you in advance.

I created a file in a new Jupyter notebook. Some lines of code run abnormally slowly; in some cases, they take minutes to run. No errors or warnings pop up when the cells execute. I've tried to execute the same script on Colaboratory, and the problem stays pretty much the same.

The following is the first "preliminary" cell. It raises no errors and has never caused any similar problem when I've used it in other scripts.

```
%matplotlib inline
%matplotlib widget

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
```

This line of code (when run alone in a separated cell) takes 10-20 seconds to execute:

```
f = c*[1/472e-9, 1/505e-9, 1/525e-9, 1/588e-9, 1/611e-9]
```

where `c = 299792458` is the speed of light in m/s.

The following takes anywhere from 30 seconds up to several minutes to execute. If I run each line in a separate cell, they execute instantly without errors. When put together, they suddenly become abnormally slow. I should also point out that the CSVs contain only 20 numbers each, correctly formatted to give a 20-row column vector when imported. Quite literally a text file with 20 three-digits numbers, each one on a different consecutive row, without spaces, empty lines, commas or anything else.

```
intens = np.arange(5,101,5)

A = np.loadtxt('A.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True)
A = np.flip(A)*1e-3

B = np.loadtxt('B.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True)
B = np.flip(B)*1e-3

C = np.loadtxt('C.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True)
C = np.flip(C)*1e-3

D = np.loadtxt('D.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True)
D = np.flip(D)*1e-3

E = np.loadtxt('E.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True)
E = np.flip(E)*1e-3
```

I'm running Jupyter through Anaconda on a MacBook Air M1, which I use only for PDF reading and editing, Matlab coding, LaTeX writing and Python.

I've checked memory usage: there's more than 400 GB of free space on my Mac. RAM usage increases dramatically when I run the slowest parts of the code. System monitoring app doesn't report anything anomalous, I think. There's nothing running in background.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77698572/kernel-dying-at-the-end-of-the-script-what-could-it-be/77699280#77699280) question has been suggested in the comments; while that issue seems related to mine, there's still no satisfying answer. Someone suggested it can be a problem related to the libraries I import, which run and may execute on C. However, I've already used them in this exact fashion and I can't see what's different here.

Comment: This isn't reproducible as you've posted it here.  'They take an abnormal amount of time to be compiled (the fastest one takes 20s). ' Compiled? Do you mean executed? (You do say English isn't your language so maybe that explains that?) "My other scripts run perfectly everywhere and every time." Okay. So what is different here? Make a toy example you can share with others or your post isn't really answerable. Google Colab runs the computation on a remote computer and so it needs an internet connection. It is a highly customized older version of Jupyter.

Comment: <continued> "'I've written a couple of very simple code cells in a new notebook through Jupyter Notebooks," Just because the code looks simple or concise doesn't mean it is not doing a lot or isn't doing complex things you have invoked from things you imported like numpy and scipy. What you describe on your local computer sounds just like exhausting your system's memory because you aren't appreciating the magnitude of what is going on when executing your code. But bear in mind that is just basing it on your words & imports because you really aren't providing much details we can run ourselves.

Comment: <continued> About that last part, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77699280/8508004).

Comment: @Wayne thank you for the kind advice and sorry for the language barrier (yes, I meant "executed", I guess).
I'm not sure what you mean about providing details: I've just created a new Jupyter notebook and wrote the three cells I posted. Of course, the third one should go at the top, then there's the "first cell", then the "second". You can absolutely run everything in this order on a new notebook, there's nothing else. Well, the code was actually supposed to do something else, but I couldn't go on due to the issue I explained. Or maybe I am missing something?
Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @Wayne I've read the post you linked. I'm not encountering any system limitations I'm aware of, at least concerning memory usage, and I don't think any of the libraries I imported run and execute on C. I'm double checking, just to be sure, but the four libraries I've wrote about have been used in dozens of other much more demanding scripts, so I don't see how can they become an issue right now. Hope this helps understanding the problem! Thanks.

Comment: I am fairly confident numpy relies a lot on C and so does scipy. Evidence: see about Numpy [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/index.html) or this statement [here](https://numpy.org/) ==> "The core of NumPy is well-optimized C code." Similarlay for SciPy, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825950/8508004). As to providing details, we have no knowledge of what or how big your CSV files are. Along those line you aren't detailing when things slow down? A particular cell or line? ...

Comment: <continued> Adding to confusion and making hard to assess what you are seeking is that you then admitted the code blocks were provided out of order. **Normally if you seek speed, you run Python separate from Jupyter on the command line using traditional scripts. That removes Jupyter from the equation because I think you are after Python questions and not Jupyter here.** Doing that would get you a step torwards determining your bottleneck/issues. No where yet have you brought up versions of your Python or packages and that can have a lot of effect. Please read ...

Comment: <continued> and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the links. My CSV files contain 20 numbers each, separated by commas. I've tried running a separate cell for each line of the code: `f = c*[1/472e-9, 1/505e-9, 1/525e-9, 1/588e-9, 1/611e-9]` is the slowest. Moreover, if I try running `blu = np.loadtxt('blu.csv',delimiter=',',unpack=True)`, `blu=np.flip(blu)\*1e-3` and the others separately, they execute instantly, while if they run together they take more than 30 seconds. What does "running Python separate from Jupyter on the command line" mean? Thanks again. I'll edit my post to make it more adherent to the guidelines.

Comment: Now given that updated information I am less sure that running your code separately as a traditional Python script is going to help much for overall speed. Python directly may though be less limited than Jupyter memory wise though and so maybe. It may though work better because the version of Python and the packages may be different. So it may even be slower if the Python & packages happen to be older and less optimized.  For the record, Python traditionally is a language run as text in a console or scripts that get called by Python and run on the command line. For convenience, IPython ....

Comment: <continued> added more interactive features to Python. However, it is still at its heart run on the console or via text scripts calling IPython to run them. IPython Notebook added the first graphical user interface to IPython with the cells that you step through running. Finally, when other kernels were introduced for other languages the IPython Notebook project evolved into the Jupyter Project. That hopefully provides some more history and may be important as you encounter different advice. So I would try these as Python on your machine. It may give you more guidance and options. In fact, ...

Comment: <continued> considering part of your stuff is dealing with using Python for some math, you may want to read about a lot of what I just stated [here at 'Numerical Methods using Python'](https://hmanikantan.github.io/ECH60/) by going there and selecting to read the 'Introduction' section, especially the 'Python, more generally' section. (The rest of that material my be useful for you, too.) If you are seeing the individual manipulations of your CSV files run instantly but take 30 seconds when you run them as a chunk in Jupyter, it may indeed be communication back to Jupyter from the Python ...

Comment: <continued> kernel that is causing the delay. And running them directly in Python will be better. Personally, I think you are getting caught up in a non-problem here. Instantly vs 30 seconds isn't really an issue. Python is not generally known for speed but has become better especially recently. It is used because it is a high level language that is easier to work with than C directly. Your updated comment "However, I've already used them in this exact fashion and I can't see what's different here" really seems at odds with what you are saying. Did your Mac become slower lately or is the ...

Comment: <continued> code different and therefore isn't the 'exact fashion'. At the time I referenced [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77698572/8508004) it was in part because your post was not well-written and the comment summarized what you could be nearly encountering. Since your issue doesn't cause the kernel to crash (or does it?) then it is indeed different. However, it could be related because you are running code that is doing some heavy lifting. And it doesn't matter there is no satisfactory answer in that post because there won't be. To do heavy computation, you need resources. There's ...

Comment: <continued> plenty of other ones saying much the same thing. It is just I happened along that one when I was looking something up. Also if you want to make reproducible code, you'd supply us with code to make such CSVs like you are using. Numpy or Pandas can easily do that. That suggestion is meant for future reference mostly. If you wanted to pursue this further it would be helpful because others could benchmark from it. However, I think you are chasing minor problems here right now & constantly moving the goal posts. Before you mentioned Colab and now that is gone but remains in topic tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least one problem. Multiplying a list by an integer repeat elements:

```
5 * [1, 2, 3]
# [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Therefore the following call:

```
299792458 * [1/472e-9, 1/505e-9, 1/525e-9, 1/588e-9, 1/611e-9]
```

Creates a huge list repeating the five elements and taking about 5.5 Go in RAM. Which explains why it takes 30 seconds everywhere: it's time to room space in RAM to allocate the list.

If you are looking for element-wise multiplication use `ndarray` instead

```
5 * np.array([1, 2, 3])
# array([ 5, 10, 15])
```

Comment: Using `np.array([...])` instead of just `[...]` solved everything. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you very much!

Comment: done. Sorry, I was not sure how to do it in the first place. Thanks again.